# Appending multiple digest signatures to a file using signtool

Tags: code-signing, digest, signtool

I am trying to sign a .exe file using signtool's digest signing option with several signatures while appending them.
For each signature I am using */dg* to create the digest, then */ds* to sign it and then */di* to ingest it and sign the .exe file.
Didn't quite understand how and when to use */as*. Should it replace the next */di* step? Should it be done after?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I think it is not possible. The last signature always overrides the previous one